# How can I get rid of this ruby warning?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, macports

I have just installed ruby 1.9.1-p429 with macports. Every time I use it, it displays this error message:

```
$ ruby1.9 -e "puts 'hi.'"
Error loading gem paths on load path in gem_prelude
can't modify frozen string
<internal:gem_prelude>:69:in `force_encoding'
<internal:gem_prelude>:69:in `set_home'
<internal:gem_prelude>:38:in `dir'
<internal:gem_prelude>:76:in `set_paths'
<internal:gem_prelude>:47:in `path'
<internal:gem_prelude>:286:in `push_all_highest_version_gems_on_load_path'
<internal:gem_prelude>:355:in `<compiled>'
hi.
```

Comment: Not an answer, but I recently installed that patch-level using rvm and got the same result. So, my guess is that it's Ruby rather than you or MacPorts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug: [see bug report here](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/2404)

I don't know if either is available from MacPorts, but Ruby 1.9.1-p378 and 1.9.2-rc1 are both free of the problem.

If you haven't already tried it, I highly recommend [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) for multiple Ruby interpreters.